# XO or Target Group - Best option to Personalize Content in Tridion Sites?

Tags: dxa, smarttarget, dxa-2.0, experience-optimization

We are using SDL Tridion Sites 9 with DXA 2.0 (Java).

I have a requirement where we want to display the targeted/personalized content (hero banner or teaser or any other Component) based on the registered user profile. i.e:

- if the user profile is X display x-banner
- if the user profile is Y display y-banner
- or let's say if the user is not logged in then display the teaser Component with registration link else something related to x/y content.

The user is authenticated by a 3rd party system & we persist the logged-in state in the cookie.

Can anyone help me to understand if we should use Experience Optimization or the personalization based on Target Group(Profiling/Personalization) or some custom-built solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest best to go for Experience Optimization + some custom build solution.

In SDL Tridion Sites 9.0+ Experience Optimization (XO) - Integrates with very powerfull elasticsearch (replaced Fredhopper) and very extensible and powerfull to manage the rules.

Note that Personalization and Profiling functionality is [legacy API (in-process)](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites%20legacy-v1/GUID-7092414B-F235-43AA-9198-BC7651840CA0) and is not available in the SDL Tridion Sites 9 CIL API.

You can also use Experience Optimization using the DXA Experience Optimization Module.

**Update:** Just my thought

OOTB You can use the following trigger types for the logged-in state.
[image]

For the user-profile, you can create a new trigger type UserId as text field you can pass user profile.

Bofore the promotional trigger, either you can pass those claims values from web applicaiton or you could also build ADF Cartridge with your CRM userprofile to pass those claims to achieve this promotional content.

[Experience Optimization cartridge reference](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-4FAA9496-42A6-4C12-BD69-6490662A4A5C) for Session cartridge and Audience Manager cartridge

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Velmurugan, as I mentioned that we are relying on a 3rd party system to authenticate the user as well as to get the user details like user profile (we are not using Audience Manager), can we define the trigger on the logged-in state & user profile. As the official SDL document only talks about the Session-based or Audience Manager based triggers? Is there any other reference that can provide more information?

Comment: Updated my answer